# Aurelia: Binding to computed values

Tags: javascript, aurelia

In my application I need to have some forms with rows of values that have to be summed. I need to loop through these rows, having inputs for them and then building a sum that should be updated when the inputs are edited.

Here is a simplified example:
The class:

```
export class example {
    items = [
        { id: 1, val: 100 },
        { id: 2, val: 200 },
        { id: 3, val: 400 }
    ];

    get sum() {
        let sum = 0;
        for (let item of this.items) {
            sum = sum + parseFloat(item.val);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

The view:

```
<div repeat.for="item of items" class="form-group">
    <label>Item ${$index}</label>
    <input type="text" value.bind="item.val" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Summe</label>
    <input type="text" disabled value.one-way="sum" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;" />
 </div>
```

Until here everything is working like I expect it to do. But: it's dirty checking on `sum` all the time and I fear running into performance issues in the more complicated app. So I tried to use the `@computedFrom` decorator, but none of these versions works:

```
@computedFrom('items')

@computedFrom('items[0]', 'items[1]', 'items[3]')

@computedFrom('items[0].val', 'items[1].val', 'items[3].val')
```

In all of these cases, the sum is just calculated once but not after editing the values. And the last 2 would be no good solution, because I can have a changing amount of items in my model.

Any suggestions how I could get a computed value that is changed when fields which it depends on are changed without having the dirty checking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `@computedFrom` on the item `val` prop:

```js
import {computedFrom} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Item {
  constructor(id, val, parent) {
    this.id = id;
    this._val = val;
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  @computedFrom('_val')
  get val() {
    return this._val;
  }
  set val(newValue) {
    this._val = newValue;
    this.parent.calculateSum();
  }
}

export class Example {
  sum = 0;

  items = [
    new Item(1, 100, this),
    new Item(2, 200, this),
    new Item(3, 400, this)
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.calculateSum();
  }

  calculateSum() {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let item of this.items) {
      sum = sum + parseFloat(item.val);
    }
    this.sum = sum;
  }
}
```

For some other ideas, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32019971/725866

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the complete code. It worked for me even in my more complicated model.