# Observe property on an array of objects for any changes

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am using [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io) and I have an array of items bound to a grid and they have a selected property on them. I want to bind a button to be enabled when any one of the items is true. I can do a brute force approach where I have a getter that is filtering the list and returning the selected items, but that means that I would be doing dirty checking constantly in the app and I don't want to do that. I am hoping for a more efficient approach. Any ideas?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Few things you could do- assuming I have your use case right:

## dirty-checking (it's only one property- not a big deal)

```js
export class Item {
  selected = false;
}

export class ViewModel {
  items = [new Item(), new Item(), new Item()];

  get anySelected() {
    var items = this.items, i = items.length;
    while(i--) {
      if (items[i].selected) {
        return true; 
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

## observe the items

```js
import {BindingEngine, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Item {
  selected = false;
}

@inject(BindingEngine)
export class ViewModel {
  items = [new Item(), new Item(), new Item()];    
  anySelected = false;
  subscriptions = [];

  constructor(locator) {
    this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
  }

  updateAnySelected() {
    var items = this.items, i = items.length;
    while(i--) {
      if (items[i].selected) {
        this.anySelected = true;
        return;
      }
    }
    this.anySelected = false;
  }

  activate() {
    var items = this.items, i = items.length, observer;
    while(i--) {
      observer = this.bindingEngine.propertyObserver(items[i], 'selected');
      subscriptions.push(observer.subscribe(() => this.updateAnySelected());
    }
    this.updateAnySelected();
  }

  deactivate() {
    let dispose;
    while(subscription = subscriptions.pop()) {
      subscription.dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

## use a collection class

```js
import {computedFrom} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Item {
  _selected = false;

  constructor(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  @computedFrom('_selected')
  get selected() {
    return this._selected;
  }
  set selected(newValue) {
    newValue = !!newValue;
    if (newValue === _selected) {
      return;
    }
    _selected = newValue;
    this.parent.itemChanged(newValue);
  }
}

export class Items {
  items = [];
  selectedCount = 0;
  anySelected = false;

  createItem() {
    let item = new Item(this);
    this.items.push(item);
    return item;
  }

  itemChanged(selected) {
    this.selectedCount += (selected ? 1 : -1);
    this.anySelected = this.selectCount > 0;    
  }
}

export class ViewModel {
  items = new Items();

  constructor() {
    let item = this.items.createItem();
    item = this.items.createItem();
    item = this.items.createItem();
  }
}
```

## use a `selectedItems` array instead of a selected boolean prop

```js
export class ViewModel {
  items = [{}, {}, {}];
  selectedItems = [];

  selectItem(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
  }

  deselectItem(item) {
    this.items.splice(this.items.indexOf(item), 1);
  }
}
```

*for binding purposes, use `selectedItems.length` as your "any selected" property*

Comment: Awesome! Some great options here. Thank you.

Comment: Has this changed?

Comment: Yes... Has this changed?

Comment: No- has not changed

Comment: Thanks for _for binding purposes, use selectedItems.length_

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Jeremy's examples, you can create a custom setter, for example:

```
class Item {
   // this is your ~private~ field
  _isSelected = false;

  // in our constructor, we pass the view model and the property name
  constructor(vm, prop, name) {
    this.vm = vm;
    this.prop = prop;
    this.name = name;
  }

  get isSelected() {
    return this._isSelected;
  }
  // when you set the value, you increase the vm's property
  set isSelected(value) {
    if (value !== this._isSelected) {
      this.vm[this.prop] += value ? 1 : -1;
      this._isSelected = value;
    }
  }
}

export class MyViewModel
{
  items = [];
  itemsSelected = 0; // that's the property we'll pass to the class we've created

  constructor() 
  {
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      // instead of adding a annonymous {} here, we add an instance of our class
      this.items.push(new Item(this, 'itemsSelected', `Item ${i+1}`));
    }
  }

  toggleIsSelected(item) {
    item.isSelected = !item.isSelected;
  }
}
```

I've created a plunker for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/OTb2RDLZHf5Fy1bVdCB1?p=preview

---

Doing that, you'll never be looping to see if some item has changed.

Comment: This is the same as the "use a collection class" example, although it's missing the `@computedFrom('_isSelected')` decorator on the isSelected getter function which means isSelected will be dirty-checked.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also leverage `EventAggregator` as shown [here](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#the-event-aggregator). In that way there is no need to perform dirty checking all the time and instead handle the item selection event in its own VM and publish the eventdata; the subscriber on the other side will listen to the same and perform the gymnastic needed.

However, I have never used it, so I am not sure about the deeper details of it. But from the documentation it looks pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy got me thinking about this [in this bug](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/309). So it looks like you can also get the binding refreshing via a custom Binding Behaviors. Hopefully Jeremy can confirm I'm not doing anything too silly here.

Used like this:

`repeat.for="item of items | filter & array:'propertyName'"`

It overrides the standard observe behaviour and observes on the array and the property you define on each item. It can probably be improved to be more generic...

```
function observeProperty(obj, property) {
  this.standardObserveProperty(obj, property);
  let value = obj[property];
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    this.observeArray(value); 
    for(let each of value){   
      this.standardObserveProperty(each, this.propertyName); 
    }
  }
}

export class ArrayBindingBehavior {
  bind(binding, source, property) {
    binding.propertyName = property;
    binding.standardObserveProperty = binding.observeProperty;
    binding.observeProperty = observeProperty;
  }

  unbind(binding, source) {
    binding.observeProperty = binding.standardObserveProperty;
    binding.standardObserveProperty = null;
    delete binding.propertyName;
  }
}
```